# Facebook Graph API URL Format - Get more than 25 results

Tags: facebook-graph-api, rcurl

I am struggling to form that right URL to use Facebook Graph API to access Insights data.

I currently get only 25 results and I want to extend that to the max - I understand max is 5000.

My request URL is:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/act_317691597/insights?access_token=tok&time_range={'since':'2015-06-01','until':'2015-07-31'}&time_increment=1
```

I want to know how to reformat the URL string to:
1. Use the limit parameter and get more than 25 results 
2. Get only the "spend" and "date_start" data points in the response (I dont need the rest)

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the limit parameter is easy, you just...add it as parameter ;)

For example:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/someendpoint?limit=100
```

Afaik the max limit is 100, you have to use paging if you want to get more entries: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.4#paging

If you only want to get specific fields, use declarative fields:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/someendpoint?limit=100&fields=field1,field2,...
```